# Glimpse MVC tabs empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I am trying to get Glimpse for Mvc5 working. I have a project in VS2013 in Mvc5 (Razor v3 / C# / .NET 4.5). I have installed Glimpse.Mvc5 using NuGet and have everything configured by default. I can access `/Glimpse.axd` and I can open the clientside panel.

In the panel I can see all the MVC tabs (Execution, Views, Model Binding, Metadata).

When I click any MVC tab, for example Execution, no data is displayed. What am I missing? All other tabs are functioning well. The Glimpse log shows many of these messages:

```
2013-11-08 14:22:33.0306 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 14:22:33.0462 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. |
```

This is part of my `web.config`:

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <logging level="Trace" />
    <inspectors>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.DependencyInjectionInspector, Glimpse.Mvc5"/>
      </ignoredTypes>
    </inspectors>
  </glimpse>
```

EDIT:

I compared my log file against a default MVC5 template application, they seem identical except where the default application ends with:

```
2013-11-08 19:01:34.6017 | INFO | Replaced IView of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView', named 'Index', with proxy implementation. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:35.9939 | INFO | Replaced IView of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView', named '_LoginPartial', with proxy implementation. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:36.3019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:36.4799 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. |
```

My log ends with:

```
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8688 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8868 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8868 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8868 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8868 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.8978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9128 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9318 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9318 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9318 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9318 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9478 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9478 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9478 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:45.9598 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.1938 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.1978 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6019 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6159 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6159 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6159 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:54:46.6699 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ModifyResponseHeaders' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.AjaxPolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:55:38.4025 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:55:38.4185 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:55:38.4375 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:56:38.7171 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:56:38.7171 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:56:38.7342 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:57:38.7975 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:57:38.7975 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:57:38.8145 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:38.8937 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:38.8937 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:38.9097 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5404 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5404 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5404 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5404 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5404 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5474 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5634 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:58.5784 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ExecuteResourceOnly' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'ExecuteResource'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2525 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:58:59.2825 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'ModifyResponseHeaders' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.AjaxPolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:59:38.9730 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:59:38.9730 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 18:59:38.9900 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:00:39.0562 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:00:39.0722 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:00:39.0942 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:39.2146 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:39.2336 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:01:39.2566 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:02:39.3721 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:02:39.3891 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. | 
2013-11-08 19:02:39.4091 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'BeginRequest'. |
```

Comment: What Glimpse packages have you got installed? Also any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: Are there any JS errors being thrown?

Comment: Could a custom viewengine be the cause of this problem?

Comment: No JS errors. I am using Glimpse.Core 1.7.0.0, Glimpse.AspNet 1.5.0.0 and Glimpse.Mvc5 1.5.0.0 all from NuGet package. Screen: http://i41.tinypic.com/jicl0n.png

Answer (score 0):

I am a Stackoverflow newbie so I don't know how to upload pictures yet my Glimpse shows execution data.

first difference your web.config Glimpse section does not match mine.  Mine looks like this:

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<!-- 
      For more information on how to configure Glimpse, please visit http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration
      or access {your site}/Glimpse.axd for even more details and a Configuration Tool to support you. 
  -->
```

My packages.config shows I have the following versions:
- Glimpse version="1.8.4" targetFramework="net451"
- Glimpse.Ado version="1.7.0" targetFramework="net451"
- Glimpse.AspNet version="1.8.1" targetFramework="net451"
- Glimpse.EF6 version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net451"
- Glimpse.Mvc5 version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net451"
- EntityFramework version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net451"